# Expo Electron OAuth2 Login

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, electron, expo, expo-web

I'm trying to built an app using Expo for multiple different Platforms, Desktop included - with Electron.
Now I'm having issues continuing a logging process till the end.

I'm aware Electron uses Expo React Native Web Features, but I don't understand how to do continue the logging process after the redirection.

This is what I've tried:

```js
const useProxy = Platform.OS !== 'web';

export function AuthScreen() {
const {nextState} = useAuth();

    const discovery = AuthSession.useAutoDiscovery('https://my-open-id.url');

    const redirectUri = AuthSession.makeRedirectUri({
        useProxy,
    });

    // Create and load an auth request
    const [request, , promptAsync] = AuthSession.useAuthRequest(
        {
            clientId: 'client-id',
            clientSecret: 'client-secret',
            redirectUri,
            scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'offline_access'],
        },
        discovery
    );

    const login = useCallback(async () => {
        const result = await promptAsync({useProxy});
        console.log({result});

        if (!result) {
            return;
        }

        switch (result.type) {
            case "cancel":
            case "dismiss":
                return;
            case "error":
                return;
            case "locked":
                return;
            case "success":
                const token = result.authentication;
                nextState(token);
                return;
        }
    }, [promptAsync]);

    if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
        useEffect(() => {
            WebBrowser.warmUpAsync();
            return () => {
                WebBrowser.coolDownAsync();
            }
        }, []);
    }

    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Text>Auth Screen</Text>
            <Button title="Login!" disabled={!request} onPress={login}/>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Whenever I click on the `Login` button, I'm being redirected to my OAuth2 server and I can log in. After that, I'm supposed to be redirected into my app, but no.

[image]

After the login process, the new window remains and another instance of the application continues there.

[image]

I'm looking also for electron features to know how to hack it sufficiently so have a fully working flow, but I still don't know how to access electron's main process from the react native part of the code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expo is using a [Private URI Scheme](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/#usage-in-standalone-apps) to listen for the login resonse, so first ensure that you have registered it correctly according to the docs.

**RECEIVING DEEP LINKS**

Once you know your your app's scheme, an easy way to test it is via commands like this, depending whether running on Mac or Windows:

```sh
open x-mycompany-desktopapp:/somepath
start x-mycompany-desktopapp:/somepath
```

I would make sure login happens in the system browser, as recommended in [RFC8252](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252#section-7.1). Avoid logins on React Native windows.

In the browser you should see prompts to return the login response to the app. There are some screenshots in this [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/26/final-desktop-sample-overview/) of mine for a plain Electron OAuth secured app.

**ELECTRON MULTI INSTANCE LOGIC**

My [Electron OAuth desktop code sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample.final) uses a Private URI Scheme and deals with the multi instance issue you mention - see [this code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample.final/blob/master/src/main.ts#L27) and the use of `requestSingleInstanceLock`.

Hopefully these notes give you some clues and possible actions. When I was developing this, a big landmark was being able to capture log statements from my `main.ts` source file!

OAuth is tricky to implement in UIs and sometimes higher level technologies such as Expo can give you very little visibility.